# How to show div line by line - template Angular

Tags: angular, templates, show

I have an angular template displaying rows. I added a button to display some informations on the current line. The problem is : when I click on the button line 1, the informations was showed on all the lines.

I put here a little snippet of the code reproducing my problem

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmhrty

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you need to control which button did you click, I put this information inside de array, I hope it helps you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bawglg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let test of items; index as i" >
  <div class="resultRow newRow" [class.resultRow-mobile]="mobileMode">
        <div *ngIf="!mobileMode" class="expandThis">
            <span (click)="toggleDocuments(i)">CLICK</span>
        </div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="visibleDocuments[i]">
            <p>OK</p>
        </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  show:boolean = false;
  items:any[] = ['1', '2'];
  visibleDocuments = new Array(this.items.length);

  toggleDocuments(index){
        this.visibleDocuments[index] = !this.visibleDocuments[index];
    }

}
```

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgvpa8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I forked your snippet and updated it with what I think you're looking for:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gt3jmk

I'm suggesting that you store the state of show / not show in each item that you want to display. That way, you can toggle the visibility of each individually. You can do this by adding a `show` property to each item in addition to its data.

Answer (score 0):

This an example of solution :

**componet:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  item1: {info: string, show: boolean} = {info:'item 1 - info', show: false};
  item2: {info: string, show: boolean} = {info:'item 2 -info', show: false};
  items = [this.item1, this.item2];

  toggleDocuments(item: {info: string, show: boolean}){
        item.show = ! item.show;
    }

}
```

template :

```
<div *ngFor="let test of items" >
  <div class="resultRow newRow" [class.resultRow-mobile]="mobileMode">
        <div *ngIf="!mobileMode" class="expandThis">
            <span (click)="toggleDocuments(test)">CLICK</span>
        </div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="test.show">
            <p>{{test.info}}</p>
        </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```